# MySQL - Does using an explicit transaction affect query performance?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

In MySQL 5.6, using InnoDB, I have a rather large table, call it A; (about 4 million rows) in which I need to update a field. The condition regarding what to update is held in another table, B; and the relation between the two is also held in another table, C; so I created my update statement with two joins, like so :

```
UPDATE A a JOIN (B b, C c) ON (conditions) SET a.myField = 'myValue'
```

Now I tested this statement on a dump of my target database, on a equivalent machine. Because I needed this dump for other purposes, I tested the thing using a transaction in order to rollback afterwards :

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE [...]
ROLLBACK;
```

Which gave me pretty good performance (I think) for my update, about 17 seconds and 8 for the rollback.

**My question is this**: If I were to run this statement as is, not in a transaction, on my target database, would I obtain the same performance ? In other words, does using explicit transactions affect performance, and if yes, how ?

I tried to look the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) on this but it is rather sparse on this topic.

Comment: Single query is always a hidden transaction.

Comment: @Akina It is, so can I assume my query's execution time would be the same as my transaction's total execution time ? A naive question, I'll give you that.

Comment: Yes and no in the same time. Explicit transaction, I think, must be slightly more expensive. But I am not sure it can be detected. You may test it...

Comment: 17 seconds sounds quite a long time for an update of a few rows. `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (a select query that looks like the `UPDATE` query you have without changing anything. Have you increased the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) and [innodb_log_file_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html) from the defaults?

Comment: In my experience I had 500-1000 insert queries and there were executed by php loop. It took 40-60 seconds. I put them in transaction and the time was 5-7 seconds for execution

Comment: @danblack I will update about 350 000 rows out of 4 million. Considering the joins, is 17 seconds that bad ? `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` tells me I will use `ref` and `eq_ref` join types, I guess this is pretty good. As for the variables, both`innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_log_file_size` were increased from the default by a factor 3, although I didn't do that myself.

Comment: @Akina I could test the thing, turns out using the explicit Transaction takes about 24 seconds; whereas the single query took a little under 20 seconds. Good call, If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think it will be more useful for other users if YOU will post your environ/statistic and experimental results. You can add some details which may help somebody in a similar situation.

Comment: Ok for a lot of rows its sounding ok with the ref/eq_ref index use. 3*default still sounds rather small on such a large change.

Comment: Please use `JOIN`, not `,`.

Comment: @Akina - a single query is _not_ a transaction when it is between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

Comment: @RickJames Single query is **always** a transaction. In case of *between BEGIN and COMMIT* it is nested transaction. Otherwise, partial execution of the query (until error - by unique index violation, for example) would be possible.

Comment: @Akina - Hmmm...  I am having trouble devising a test that proves or disproves you assertion.  For example, in the case of a power failure, everything rolls back to the `BEGIN`, so you assertion is neither substantiated or not.

Comment: @Akina - Perhaps these have the answer:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216994/1876 and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-error-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

1: Using autocommit to automatically commit each transaction:

```
SET autocommit = ON;
UPDATE ...
```

2: Explicitly turning a single statement into a transaction.  This is 'identical' to #1.

```
BEGIN;     (aka START TRANSACTION;)
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

3: Multiple statements in a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...;
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

4: Don't use this; some day you will forget to `COMMIT`:

```
SET autocommit = OFF;
UPDATE ...;
...
eventually: COMMIT;
```

5: Not advised.  It can lead to slowdowns due to overflowing the "log":

```
BEGIN;
a million statements
COMMIT;
```

Notes:

- Each SQL has some small overhead (network transmission; parsing; etc)
- Each transaction as a noticeable overhead.  In particular there is disk I/O to make it crash-safe.  Hence #3 is faster than two copies of #1 or #2.
- See `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` for a tradeoff between integrity and speed.

Advice:

- First priority: Do what the application needs -- this is, put the appropriate number of statements in each transaction.
- Lower priority: Throw together multiple statements when suitable, thereby amortizing the transaction overhead.
- In the case of `INSERT`, it is even better to have a single `INSERT` statement with multiple rows.  Davit's Comment show a 9x speedup by putting multiple `INSERTs` in a single transaction.  That is similar to the effect of the single batch insert.
- Use `ROLLBACK` only when appropriate.  It is costly.  This is because InnoDB optimizes for `COMMIT` and has to do extra effort to undo.
- For performance improvements, this whole discussion is pretty far down the checklist.  More important things involve indexing and query formulation.
- Multi-thousand-row `DELETE` and `UPDATE` have a lot of overhead and stress on the log.  It is better to break them up.

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete answer but nonetheless, here it is.

Following suggestions from the comments, I made a few tests and obtained the following performance.
The question's query modified 350 000 rows out of 4 million.

Using the explicit transaction mentionned above took about 24 seconds, whereas the query alone took a little under 20 seconds.

It turns out using an explicit transaction looks more expensive than a single query. I cannot understand why though, so I'll have to search on that.

Some details about my system [variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html):
`innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size` were increased from the default by a factor 3. For this particular test's purpose I set `query_cache_type` to 0 (from 1). Performance of our application dropped quite dramatically afterwards, but since it's a test machine, it's fine.
Also, the MySQL server is managed through [systemd](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-systemd.html), where we modified the `LimitNOFILE` param to 8192. This file's other parameters are I think irrelevant.

About the query, `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` showed that only `req` and `eq_ref` join types were used.
In the end, I will go for the single query on my target database as it is faster.